# male/female cousin or nephew/niece

Tags: kinship-terms, gender-neutral

I was reading true some of the gender questions on this site. They said that there where no gender specific way of saying cousin except adding male or female in front of it. But i was always told you could also use nephew or niece in place of. Is this because of the american influences on the English language or was this added because of the non English learning English and added it over time.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nephew_and_niece

Comment: Nephew and niece have a different meaning than cousin. Indeed, a cousin (if not "removed") is of the same generation you are, while a niece or nephew is one generation younger.

Comment: You can't use *nephew* in place of *cousin* unless your cousin is his own father. I'm no medical expert, but I believe that's impossible. (Unless of course he has a time machine)

Comment: Surely the fact that the page you link to says that some people would use *niece* or *nephew* for particular types of cousin (your first-cousins' children) by itself shows that one in fact cannot just use *niece* or *nephew* in place of *cousin* all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But i was always told you could also use nephew or niece in place of.

You were always told wrong then.

There are certainly cases where some cousins might be referred to as such, such as your parents' siblings' childrens' children (your first-cousins-once-removed in the younger generations) though that isn't universal but found in some cultures more than others, and with some family traditions going beyond that.

My mother's family used it even of first cousins when there was a great disparity in age, and so I called her sister's daughter (hence my cousin) my "aunt" and she called me her "nephew" as she was much older than me, but then my father's family who also had a great range of ages among his siblings did not have the same practice. It was a very localised thing.

And even allowing for such very localised conventions, one would not refer to all cousins as *nieces* and *nephews*.